# How can I wait until all my images are loaded before adding them to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to get multiple images from an ajax source and load the on the page when they have all finished loading. The issue I was having that has caused me to try to find a solution was that some of the images weren't loading even though those images existed on the server. 
[image]

I have tried to add code that now adds the image to an array

```
design_images.push({cid:designImg});
```

... and then when all the images have loaded will add that to the page, but I can't get that to work.

```
var counter = 0;
$(design_images).load(function() { // many or just one image(w) inside body or   any other container
 counter += 1;

  }).each(function(key, value) {
  this.complete && $(this).load();    
  console.log(value);
});
```

Nothing is outputted from the .each

This is the output of the array design_images
[image]

The value of design_images.length is 0 though.

Here is the complete function:

```
function matte_design_change_design_type(element)
{
  var element_value = null;
  var mattes_selected_type = get_mattes_selected_type();

  matte_design_widths[mattes_selected_type] = [];
  var mattes_selected_design = get_mattes_selected_design();
  var count_matte_designs = 0;
  var found = false;
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $.ajax(
    {
      type: "GET",
      url: SITE_URL + "/system/components/xml/" + mattes_selected_type, 
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function(xml) 
      {
        var output = [];
        var design_images = [];

        $('component', xml).each(function(i, el) 
        {
          matte_design_widths[mattes_selected_type][i] = 0;
          count_matte_designs++;
          var thumb = $("thumb", this).text(),
              cid = $("cid", this).first().text(),
              name = $("name", this).first().text().replace("Collage - ", ""),
              alt = name,
              description = $("description", this).first().text(),

          if (parseInt(cid, 10) === mattes_selected_design)
          {
            found = true;
            $("#matte_design_name").html(name);
            $("#matte_design_description").html(description);
          }



          var designImg = new Image();
          designImg.id = 'cid_' + cid;
          designImg.alt = alt;
          designImg.onclick = function() {
            matte_design_change(cid, mattes_selected_type);
          };
          designImg.onload = function() {
            output.push('<span class="matte_design_image_name" id="design_' + cid + '"><img id="cid_' + cid + '" />');
            output.push('<br /><span class="matte_design_name" id="matte_design_name_' + mattes_selected_type + '_' + i + '">' + name + '</span></span>');
            matte_design_increase_width(mattes_selected_type, this.width, i);

            $('#matte_designs_strip_wrapper').html(output.join(''));
          };
          designImg.src = 'https://example.com/system/components/compimg/' + thumb + '/flashthumb';

        });


        var counter = 0;
        var size = $('img').length;
        $(design_images).load(function() {
          counter += 1;

        }).each(function(key, value) {
          this.complete && $(this).load();    
          console.log(value);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I have tried waitForImages and imagesLoaded but I couldn't get them to work for me, but I'm not opposed to using either one.

Comment: Why is this down voted...please explain

Answer (score 0):

Hide all images by default using CSS

```
    img{
    display: none;
    }
```

Use Jquery to check if all loaded, then display images

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('img').fadeIn(800); //or $('img').show('slow');
});
```